# What is this very long pipe instrument?

Tags: instruments, classical-music, folk

In

at 15:25 there is a very long pipe instrument with no holes. It is supposedly a folk instrument from Argentina since the piece is *Misa Criolla* by Ramirez, which relies on a lot on Argentinian folk music. What is it called?

Screenshot for those who can't open the link:
[image: screenshot from Misa Criolla performance]

Comment: It looks and sounds like a carnyx.  But the mouth piece is different.

Comment: I googled 'Argentinian folk wind instrument',a couple of hours ago,  and the first to come up was erke.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is known as an **Erke**.

> The erke (alternatively erque, coroneta, or quepa) is a large labrophone (lip reed) instrument native to the Gran Chaco of Bolivia, northern Chile, and Argentine Northwest. (SOURCE: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erke))

[image: Man playing an Erka in a desert setting]

(PHOTO CREDIT: By N J.O. Zavalía - https://www.flickr.com/photos/122267223@N07/13614627804/, CC BY 2.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=31981921)

Comment: [The erke is composed of two or more lengths of cane joined at the ends to form a single tube. The internal nodes of the canes are removed and the exterior is often wrapped with gut or wool. The end often has an amplifier made of cow horn or brass. The instrument is blown through at the other end, and may be three to seven metres in length.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erke#Construction) Now I want to know what is the tower in the background, probably not a music.SE question.